# C File get cleared but not edited

Tags: c, file

i wanted to make a simple database using two files by putting Name at first file ("Name_database") , and putting Money in second file ("Money_database") ,but i have error which when i close both files to insert new text one close and reopen to take new text and the other don't do the same , the other file closes and don't take the new text to be inserted

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Max_Name_Chars 20
#define Max_Accounts 100

char Name_Array[Max_Accounts][Max_Name_Chars];
int Money_Array[Max_Accounts];
int NumberOfElements ;


void getDatabasesData (FILE* Name_Database , FILE* Money_Database);
int getPlayerIndexFromName(char Name [Max_Name_Chars]);
void setDataAtDatabase (FILE* Name_Database , FILE* Money_Database , char Name [Max_Name_Chars] , int Money );
void saveDataBase(FILE* Name_Database , FILE* Money_Database);


int main()
{
    FILE* Name_Database = fopen("Name_Database.txt", "a+");
    FILE* Money_Database = fopen("Money_Database.txt", "a+");

    setDataAtDatabase(Name_Database,Money_Database,"Big",50000);

    fclose(Name_Database);
    fclose(Money_Database);
    return 0;
}



void getDatabasesData (FILE* Name_Database , FILE* Money_Database)
{
    NumberOfElements = 0;
    // Add to Name_Array
    while(fgets(Name_Array[NumberOfElements], Max_Accounts, Name_Database)) {
        Name_Array[NumberOfElements][strlen(Name_Array[NumberOfElements]) - 1] = '\0';
        NumberOfElements++;
    }

    // Add to Money_Array
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfElements; i++)
    {
        fscanf(Money_Database, "%d,", &Money_Array[i] );
    }
}

int getPlayerIndexFromName(char Name [Max_Name_Chars])
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NumberOfElements ; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(Name_Array[i],Name) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void setDataAtDatabase (FILE* Name_Database , FILE* Money_Database , char Name [Max_Name_Chars] , int Money )
{
    getDatabasesData(Name_Database, Money_Database);

    int Database_Player_Index = getPlayerIndexFromName(Name);

    if (Database_Player_Index == -1)
    {
        strcpy(Name_Array[NumberOfElements],Name);
        Money_Array[NumberOfElements] = Money;
        NumberOfElements++;

        //printf("%s %d",Name_Array[NumberOfElements],Money_Array[NumberOfElements]);
    } else {
        Money_Array[Database_Player_Index] = Money;

        //printf("%s %d",Name_Array[Database_Player_Index],Money_Array[Database_Player_Index]);
    }

    saveDataBase(Name_Database,Money_Database);
}

void saveDataBase(FILE* Name_Database , FILE* Money_Database)
{
    fclose(fopen("Name_Database.txt", "w"));
    fclose(fopen("Money_Database.txt", "w"));

    for (int i = 0 ; i < NumberOfElements ; i++)
    {
        fprintf(Name_Database,"%s\n",Name_Array[i]);
        fprintf(Money_Database,"%d ",Money_Array[i]);
    }
}
```

My First file text :

Big
Big2

My second file text :
5000 1000

Comment: In `saveDataBase` the files passed are open, so what is the `fclose(fopen("Name_Database.txt", "w"));` for? To clear the file? Why do you have two file handles open to the same file? What do you expect that to do? The file handle opened for append probably won't notice that the file was just cleared. You'ld have clearer code if every file is only opened once at every point in time. And why is there a "Big2" in the file? Your code does not contain the string "Big2".

Comment: My goal from this line ` setDataAtDatabase(Name_Database,Money_Database,"Big",50000);` is to check if Big string exist on the function then we set new value to Big , other wise add Big and his money to the both files

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all , i fixed it with a dumb way i guss , i will post it anyway in case if someone fall in this problem as well.

```
void saveDataBase(FILE* Name_Database , FILE* Money_Database)
{
fclose(Name_Database);
fclose(Money_Database);

remove("Name_Database.txt");
remove("Money_Database.txt");

Name_Database = fopen("Name_Database.txt", "a+");
Money_Database = fopen("Money_Database.txt", "a+");

for (int i = 0 ; i < NumberOfElements ; i++)
{
    fprintf(Name_Database,"%s\n",Name_Array[i]);
    fprintf(Money_Database,"%d ",Money_Array[i]);
}

fclose(Name_Database);
fclose(Money_Database);
}
```